How do I generate invertible causal filters with stable deconvolution?
I'm writing a machine learning algorithm that needs to search in the space of all possible causal and invertible convolutions/filters of size $k$ represented with floating point precision for one that best minimizes entropy. That is, I start with an integer 1D signal, apply this convolution to it, round the result, and then entropy encode it. This is as far as the algorithm sees it. However, I will then need to entropy decode it, deconvolute it, and finally round again (to return to integers). However, the initial signal is large (7000 samples) and the scipy deconvolution function quickly gets unstable and returns -inf followed by nans.
I'm asking this in this Sub Stack because I think practical expertise would also be relevant in this scenario. My understanding of deconvolutions is basic at best, so any input on this would be appreciated.
Are there specific "if-and-only-if" properties that "nice" invertible causal filters have? If so, would that be enough to generate their entire space, or at least a large and representative subspace? Does the problem lie in the way I'm deconvoluting it? Are there any good resources I can learn about deconvolutions more deeply?

Minimum phase filters are causal and stable and their inverse is also minimum phase, causal and stable. Note that this in general will be IIR filters. You can certainly design minimum phase FIR filters as well but their inverse will be an IIR filter, specifically an all-pole filter.
If your application can tolerate some bulk delay, you can use linear phase FIR filters as well.
Deconvolution is tricky if you have noise and/or spectral regions of low energy or poor SNR in your signals.
